# Mongodb $in to get result in the same order as in the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an array which contains Id of a mongodb collection

```
array = [ '573163a52abda310151e5791',
         '57358e5dbd2f8b960aecfa8c',
         '573163da2abda310151e5792' ]
```

I want the result in the same order as in the array, but here I'm getting is

```
...91
...92
...8c
```

is there a way to get result in the same order?

```
   db.coll.find({
                _id: {
                    $in: array
            }
        }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            res.send(docs)
        });
```

Comment: It is strange that you get it in a different order because in my tests I get them in the exact same order, no matter the order I set them in array. Could it be that somehow your _id field is not indexed?

Answer (score 0):

am just trying this way , use forEach in mongodb , see below

this my original order in mongodb

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5736d1210a39c2547cb9d90e"),
"name" : "karthi",
"dateCreated" : ISODate("2016-05-14T17:15:27.471Z")}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5736d1380a39c2547cb9d90f"),
"name" : "ram",
"dateCreated" : ISODate("2016-05-15T17:15:27.471Z")}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5736d1420a39c2547cb9d910"),
"name" : "kala",
"dateCreated" : ISODate("2016-05-16T17:15:27.471Z")}
```

try this way

```
["karthi","kala","ram"].forEach(function(data){
db.getCollection('users').find({"name":data}).forEach(function(data1){
    print(data1)
})
})
```

my output display this order

```
karthi 
kala
ram
```

i think this useful to you